# Graph implementation in c++ using adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, graph

Here is my code for implementing Graph using adjacency matrix. The code should be Object-oriented and there is a method `isPath()` checking if there is a connection between two nodes. Some advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
protected:
    int value;
    int **graphm;

public:
    Graph(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        graphm = new int*[value];
        int k, j;
        for (k = 0; k < value; k++)
        {
            graphm[k] = new int[value];
            for (j = 0; j < value; j++)
            {
                graphm[k][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void newEdge(int head, int end)
    {
        if (head > value || end > value || head < 0 || end < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid edge!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            graphm[head - 1][end - 1] = 1;
            graphm[end - 1][head - 1] = 1;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        int i, p;

        for (i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            for (p = 0; p < value; p++)
            {
                cout << graphm[i][p] << "   ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void isPath(int head, int end)
    {
        int k, o;
        ofstream fullstore("Test.txt");

        cout << graphm[head - 1][end - 1];
        cout << endl;
        if (!fullstore.is_open())
        {
            cout << "File can't be open";
        }

        if (graphm[head - 1][end - 1] == 1)
        {
            cout << "There is an edge between " << head << " and " << end << "\n";
            fullstore << head << ", " << end;
            fullstore.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Edge not found\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int vertex, numberOfEdges, i, head, end;
    cout << "Enter number of nodes: ";
    cin >> vertex;
    numberOfEdges = vertex * (vertex - 1);
    Graph g1(vertex);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEdges; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter edge ex.1 2 (-1 -1 to exit): \n";
        cin >> head >> end;
        if ((head == -1) && (end == -1))
        {
            break;
        }
        g1.newEdge(head, end);
    }
    g1.display();
    cout << endl;
    g1.isPath(1, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?s=1|1164.7147) `using namespace std;`.

Why are you using raw pointers?  Use smart pointers, or (better yet) standard containers like `std::vector`.  Since `vector` constructs its elements, much of your initialization code can be eliminated.

Make use of the member initializer list in your constructor.  There's no real difference with fundamental types like `int`, but with more complicated objects it can be a big help or outright necessity (to initialize a reference).

```
    Graph(int value): value(value) {
```

(That will initialize the member `value` with the parameter `value`.)  Then get rid of the `this->value = value` line.

Define variables as late as possible, with their first use if possible.  Make use of this in your `for` statements.

```
for (int k = 0; k < value; ++k)
```

In `newEdge`, your parameter validation accepts 0 as a valid edge index, but you then subtract one from it for the subscripting, resulting in Undefined Behavior and a possible crash.

`display` and `isPath` should be const (`void display() const`.  `isPath` does not validate its parameters like `newEdge` does.

Answer (score 3):

### Avoid `using namespace std;`

To know why:

- Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) SO thread
- Check Standard C++ recommendations: [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std), [here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf6-use-using-namespace-directives-for-transition-for-foundation-libraries-such-as-std-or-within-a-local-scope-only)
- Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/) blog

### Memory management

#### delete

Each time you write `new` think about `delete`. (And in this case, about `delete []`). If you manually allocate memory, you should care about freeing otherwise welcome to memory leaks.

#### smart pointers

If you to have to use pointer (and ask yourself, "do I really need to?") try to use [smart pointers](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/beginner-s-look-smart-pointers-modern-c) instead of raw pointers. (and if no choice, use them [correctly](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt))

- It's the Standard [way to go](https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/an-overview-on-smart-pointers.html)
- There are [many advantages](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/22/smart-developers-use-smart-pointers-smart-pointers-basics/)
- For almost [zero-overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295665/how-much-is-the-overhead-of-smart-pointers-compared-to-normal-pointers-in-c)

### Adopt [Standards](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)

#### Containers

Choose and use [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11) types and [containers](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers).

#### Algorithms

It's really [important](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/01/05/the-importance-of-knowing-stl-algorithms/) to [know your algorithms](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-library-stl).

### Misc

#### Const-correctness

When a parameter doesn't have to change, [make it const](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

#### Includes

Include only requested header. Why including `<cstdlib>` here ?

#### iostream

[Don't close manually istream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748014/do-i-need-to-manually-close-an-ifstream) if you don't have to.

#### std::end

[Avoid using `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n). It send `'\n'` to the steam and then flush the steam. If you need to flush, do it [explicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

#### Inputtings and parameters

Always  [validate inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934183/integer-validation-for-input). Don't assume that users don't try to break your program.

#### Variables

Define variable in the [closest scope possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773396/declare-variables-at-top-of-function-or-in-separate-scopes) and use names that make sense.